# How to read properties file in Dynamic Web applicaiton

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis

I am reading properties file in the Dynamic web application as follows :

```
try
{
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("messages.properties"));
}
catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
throw new AxisFault(e.getMessage());
}
```

It's loading the messages properly without any issue and I copied it into WEB-INF/classes directory. Now, if I delete the file and trying to run the web application it's throwing NullPointerException, instead of catching and throwing Axis Fault exception.

How can I catch the exception if the message.properties file doesn't exist ?

Comment: what is causing the NPE exactly?

Comment: Thread.class calls dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) which generated NullPointerException rather than throwing AxisFault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NullPointerException is a runtime exception so the compiler won't warn you that you don't catch it. And it is not a type of IOException so it is not caught by your catch block.

You can do:

```
try {
    //do something
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
}
```

or to catch all other exceptions

```
try {
    //do something
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: even after mentioning the Exception it's not throwing the AxisFault but still calling Thread.class and calling dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) which generated NullPointerException